# Checking if column allows null values, C#?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, null

How do I check if a specified column allows null values or not?

I'm using the following code to print all the columns, but I also want to print if the column allows null values:

```
cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
cnn.Open();

SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from " + tableName, cnn);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(myCommand);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

da.Fill(ds, tableName);

foreach (DataColumn dc in ds.Tables[0].Columns)
{
     // Print stuff here, dc.ColumnName is the column name
}
```

The DataColumn.allowDBnull property doesn't seem to work when getting a predefined table, it's always set to true, even in columns that doesn't allow nulls.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are only after column data I would do this from the system views, rather than relying on the data adapter. e.g.

```
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(50) = 'dbo.TableName'

SELECT  Name, Column_ID, Is_Nullable
FROM    SYS.COLUMNS
WHERE   [Object_ID] = OBJECT_ID(@TableName)
```

This also means you can use parameterised queries properly and avoid the risks of  [SQL Injection](http://bobby-tables.com/). So your final code would  be something like this:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Name, Is_Nullable FROM sys.columns WHERE [Object_ID] = OBJECT_ID(@TableName)", connection))
{
    connection.Open();
    command.Parameters.Add("@TableName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tableName;
    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}; Allows Null: {1}", reader.GetString(0), reader.GetBoolean(1));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`SqlDataAdapter.Fill()` *Adds or refreshes rows* and does nothing in relation to a table schema information which knows whether particular column allows null. But you can use [SqlDataAdapter.FillSchema()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0te8fa0y.aspx) to load schema information, then [AllowsDBNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.allowdbnull.aspx) would show you a correct state of a column.

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(myCommand);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.FillSchema(ds, SchemaType.Source, tableName);
da.Fill(ds, tableName);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
da.FillSchema(ds, SchemaType.Source, tableName);//Loads all the constraints and relations of tables 
da.Fill(ds, tableName);//Loads the data
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
cnn.Open();

SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("
select name,is_nullable  from sys.columns where object_id=object_id('"+tableName+"')", cnn);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(myCommand);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

da.Fill(ds, tableName);

foreach (datarow in ds.Tables[0].rows)
{
    if(dr["is_nullable"].ToString()==1)
    //the column is nullable
    else
    //column is not nullable
}
```